# Highlight Cells That Contain Words From an Expanding List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I need to use a formula and conditional formatting to highlight cells that contain keywords from a list. The problem is that the list is not always the same size.

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot_Example Data]

What would be the most efficient formula to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

- Select `A2:A20`
- New formatting rule: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&COUNTA(B:B)),$A2))))>0`
- Apply formatting and confirm

While `INDIRECT` is volatile, it's okay to use in conditional formatting because conditional formatting is volatile on it's own.

Note, this will also highlight the cells that contain a words that have a keyword as substring, e.g. Motorboat will highlight with keyword Motor